# Añadir imagines a una gráfica en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy buscando como insertar una imagen en pequeñito dentro de una **gráfica** en **python**.

Algo similar a lo que busco sería como la siguiente imagen (cogida de internet):

[image: Ejemplo 1]

---

Otro ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo2]

---

Para cada gráfica generada quisiera añadir en ciertos instantes, una imagen de como se encuentra en cada momento **(realmente la quiero insertar por encima o debajo del eje)**.

¿Es posible?

Sólo se me ocurre guardar la imagen y llevármelo a **Photoshop** y colocarlas manualmente, pero son muchas gráficas y es bastante tedioso.

Comment: Aquí se muestra una forma https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-insert-an-image-a-picture-or-a-photo-in-a-matplotlib-figure/ Y [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3796404/1264820) una respuesta en StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

te paso código. Espero que te valga

```html
from PIL import Image

size = (800, 400)

img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 400), "blue") #imagen de base sobre la que queremos pegar la otra imagen
im_logo = Image.open('./img/logo.gif') #abrimos la imagen que queremos pegar
img.paste(im_logo,(100, 100)) #pegamos esa imagen a 100 pixeles del borde izquierdo y 100 pixeles del borde superior
img.save('image.png')
```

Puedes encontrar más información en https://conectabell.com/python-pillow-creando-imagenes-con-pil/